# How do predators avoid "food poisoning"?

Tags: pathology, infectious-diseases, predation

How do predators avoid becoming ill in cholera, diarrhoea, dysentery and similar diseases?

They aren't exactly careful when eating a kill, especially pack animals where there can be quite a fight over a catch and, I assume, should regularly get pieces of the large intestine in their mouth - which should be very unhealthy, shouldn't it?

Even house cats, when they eat mice and rats, seems to swallow them more or less whole and then cast up the skeleton = all contents of their prey's intestine remains in their stomach.

Comment: They’ve evolved and adapted to be able to eat what they do without getting ill (although they probably do get ill from eating bad food on occasions) because of natural selection. Remember, humans are quite different to other animals and what makes us ill doesn’t make most other animals ill.

Comment: Pet owners might disagree with you that their fluffy predators do indeed avoid food poisoning.

Comment: @BryanKrause - I immediately thought about my dogs when I read the title of this question. Luckily, the three I have right now have GI systems of steel, but some of my previous dogs... did not.

Comment: Not only "should [they] regularly get pieces of the large intestine in their mouth", but when I lived on my farm(ette) in the woods, where individuals were allowed to hunt, the dogs would *go looking for guts to eat*. We took to requiring every hunter to bury the deer's innards. The dogs would come back covered in dirt with *guts to eat*. We then took to requiring burial of innards with rocks stacked on the site. The end results of enjoying the contents of small and large intestines were unpleasant, to say the least.

Comment: Eating the meat freshly killed helps rather than letting it fester in the fridge for a week before eating it.

Comment: @user438383 So have humans. We clearly aren't that different from chimps, and they eat meat whenever they get the chance (gorillas and orangutans are more vegan). But what is the difference between humans and dogs? We mostly eat the same stuff. In what respect do you mean humans are quite different from dogs when it comes to infections and diseases?

Comment: @d-b - I would say that dogs are about as close to humans as a non-primate can get, with 50,000 years of co-evolution with us, eating our food, living with us, etc. They share hundreds of diseases with us, even rare ones. Dogs are the reason we have a treatment for narcolepsy. Their contribution to our knowledge is profound.

Comment: If you live in a country where things like cholera and dysentery  are endemic, how many healthy dogs do you see roaming around. How many are emaciated? When they die, who does autopsies on them to determine cause of death? My point is, you're making assumptions.